# Understanding proof that smooth morphism is flat ( Second question, Gortz's Algebraic geometry, Theorem 14.22 )

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Theorem 14.22 and stuck at some statement.

> Theorem 14.22. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a smooth morphism of schemes. Then $f$ is flat.

Here the 'smoothness' is defined as

[image]

*Proof ( of Theorem 14.22 ) .* Since flatness can be checked locally, it is enough to prove the assertion for a smooth morphism in "standard form" : Let $R$ be  a ring, and $f_1, \dots, f_{n-d} \in R[T_1, \dots,T_n]$ be polynomials such that for all $x\in \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots , T_n]/(f_1,\dots, f_{n-d})$, the Jacobian matrix $J_{f_1, \dots, f_{n-d}}(x)$ has rank $n-d$.

We will prove by induction on $i$ that

$$ R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1 ,\dots , f_i) = (R[T_1, \dots ,T_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1}) )/ (f_i)$$

is flat over $R$. Using Lemma 14.21

[image]

, it is enough to show that for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subset R$, $f_i$ is regular ( ;i.e., non-zero divisor ) in $A_{i-1} := (R/\mathfrak{m})[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1})$.  **But by induction hypothesis $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1}$ is smooth over the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$.** ( Next proof is omitted ).

Why the bold statement is true? I thought that I checked this statement and after looking closerly, I know that I don't make a proof rigorously. There was a loophole. It seems that we may use the fact that "for all $x\in \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots , T_n]/(f_1,\dots, f_{n-d})$, the Jacobian matrix $J_{f_1, \dots, f_{n-d}}(x)$ has rank $n-d$", but how?

EDIT : Perhaps, next statement is true?

> Q. If $\operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots , f_i) \to \operatorname{Spec}R$ is smooth, then $\operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots , f_{i-1}) \to \operatorname{Spec}R$ is smooth?

If this staement is true, then since smoothness of morphism is stable under base change, from $R \to R/\mathfrak{m}$, $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1}$ is smooth over $R/\mathfrak{m}$.

My first attempt to the question is as follows :

Note that we have $ \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1 ,\dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots,f_i) 
 \cong V(f_1 , \dots , f_i) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1 ,\dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots,f_{i-1}) \cong V(f_1, \dots, f_{i-1}) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots , T_n] = \mathbb{A}^{n}_R$.

Let $x \in V(f_1 , \dots , f_{i-1})$. It suffices to show that the Jacobian matrix $J_{f_1,\dots ,f_{i-1}}(x) \in M_{i-1 \times n}(k(x) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n_R,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x)$ has rank $i-1$.

- Case 1) $x\in V(f_1, \dots f_i)$. In this case, since $\operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \dots, T_n]/(f_1, \dots , f_i) \to \operatorname{Spec}R$ is smooth, $J_{f_!, \dots f_i}(x) \in M_{i \times n}(k(x))$ has rank $i$. So by linear algebra, $J_{f_1, \dots, f_{i-1}}(x)$ has rank $i-1$.
- Case 2) $x \in V(f_1, \dots f_{i-1}) - V(f_1, \dots, f_{i})$. In this case it is not gauranteed that $J_{f_!, \dots f_i}(x) \in M_{i \times n}(k(x))$ has rank $i$ has rank $i$ (?). How can we handle this case?

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think your edit is incorrect. For example, two surfaces in $\mathbb{A}^3$ can be intersect to give a smooth curve, but the surfaces themselves need not have been smooth themselves.

Comment: @K02 Yes. How can we show the smoothness of $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1}$ over $R/\mathfrak{m}$..

Comment: I haven't taken a careful look at the question. It seems like the point is that the $(f_1,\dots,f_{i-1})$ form a regular sequence and flatness implies that this is then smooth over the field $R/\mathfrak{m}$. It is worth pointing out that smooth is usually defined to mean flat and of finite presentation in which the geometric fibres are regular so this is why you expect such a statement to hold.

Comment: @K02 Yes. Thank you. I understand that $\operatorname{Spec}A_{i-1} \to \operatorname{Spec}R/\mathfrak{m}$ is flat and of finite presentation. And any its geometric fibers are really regular? Why? Perhaps, if the codomain is spectrum of field, then properties of flatness and of finite presentation are sufficient to show smoothness? And where can we find assoiciated proof about the criteria for smoothness of morphism?